# Yii2: Модуль админки

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Есть ли для yii2 административный модуль, который при указании модели, к примеру, будет добавлять,удалять и редактировать данные?

Answer (score 2):

Yii - это фреймворк а не CMS, никакого базового функционала кроме как добавлять пользователей там быть не может(и то без RBAC и всяких плюшек), какие данные вы хотите добавлять удалять и редактировать из коробки с отсутствием какой-либо бизнес логики?

Есть генератор gii, который может вам и модуль запилить, и CRUD и что угодно, даже со стилизацией bootstrap.

Comment: Извините, но я имел ввиду сторонние решения(модули). К примеру: Из указанных моделей создаётся список, в котором при нажатии на элемент, выскакивает форма для его редактирования.

Comment: Почитайте про виджеты фреймворка, так же на сайте yii есть раздел с расширениями, там возможно найдёте заготовки, т.к. коммьюнити большое.

Answer (score 0):

Например вот этот модуль:
[Yii2 админ модуль](https://pack-develop.info/ru/product/5)